# Upload image to firebase storage from React Dropzone (gives invalid Image)

Tags: firebase-storage, react-dropzone

I am using React Dropzone to upload files from React to firebase as shown below:

```
const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles, fileRejections) => {
    //Check if file type is image
    //Check if file size < 5MB
    //Upload
    if (fileRejections.length > 0) {
      setError(true);
    } else setError(false);
    if (acceptedFiles.length > 0) {
      const file = acceptedFiles[0];
      console.log(file);
      setFile({
        ...file,
        preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
      });
      setFileUploaded(true);
    }
  }, []);
```

and this is my upload handler:

```
  const handleImageUpload = () => {
    //Upload Image to Firebase
    //Check if file exists
    if (file !== null || file !== undefined) {
      const storageRef = ref(
        Client.storage,
        `/db-dev/user-metadata/portfolio/images/first-image.jpg`
      );
      console.log('Process begins');
      uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
        console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
      });
    }
  };
```

these two things do the work but I believe for some reason they're not encoding or decoding the image as in firebase storage folder I see image as invalid image.

Can someone help me to understand where things are going wrong? (To make sure file is loaded properly, I am also viewing the file using: `preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),` and it loads correctly in browser.

For file upload I am following the latest firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files)

It sets file type to `octet-stream` not sure what that means:
[image]

**Edit 1:** I tried to set metadata to image/jpeg:

```
uploadBytes(storageRef, file, {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
      }).then((snapshot) => {
        console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
      });
```

But now it shows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this step:

```
setFile({
        ...file,
        preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
      });
```

for some reason it wasn't spreading correctly. I changed it to:

```
setFile({
        file:file,
        preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
      });
```

and the upload function to:

```
const handleImageUpload = () => {
    //Upload Image to Firebase
    //Check if file exists
    if (file !== null || file !== undefined) {
      const storageRef = ref(
        Client.storage,
        `/db-dev/user-metadata/portfolio/images/first-image.jpg`
      );

      console.log('Process begins');
      uploadBytes(storageRef, file.file, {
        contentType: file.file.type,
      }).then((snapshot) => {
        console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
      });
    }
  };
```

and then it worked fine. Although this was a really silly thing on my part but hope this helps someone in future